# F statistic and variables

Tags: regression

Suppose you have a multiple level categorical variable $x$ (4 levels so 3 dummy variables) and you are doing a multiple linear regression against $y$ (some outcome variable). If the F test is significant does that mean at least one of the level of $x$ is linearly associated with $y$? Or does it mean that $x$ is associated with $y$?

Answer (score 6):

The entire 4-level variable *x* is what is associated with *y*.  No individual level of *x* (no value that *x* can take on) can be said to be associated with *y* because to be associated requires variation.  As an example, ethnicity can be said to be associated with income, but "being Hispanic" cannot.  On the other hand, if the variable is *whether one is Hispanic* (with 2 levels, yes and no), then such a variable can be said to be associated with another.

Comment: If there is another variable $z$, then all can say is that at least one of $x$ or $z$ is associated with $y$?

Comment: @Robbie - sounds like you are looking at the F test that tests simultaneously all the variables in your model against a null model which has only an intercept.  So "yes", that test just shows that one of x or z (or the two in combination) is associated with y.  It is possible to construct F tests to test any combination of variables however - see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21040/collapsing-regression-of-nominal-data-to-single-significance-value/21353#21353.